# I trying to create a table with hover effect, all rows overlap each other

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS:

```
#table_header {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding:10px;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#dfdbd2;
border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-ms-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#table_row {
position: relative;
padding:10px;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
display: block;
background-color: #fefdfd;
border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-ms-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#table_row:hover{ 
width: 100%;
height:auto;
padding:10px;
display: block;
background-color:#f0eade;
border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-ms-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
} 


#table_row tr td th{
color:#501214;
}

#table_wrap{
margin: 0px 0px 0 0px;
padding-top:0px;
}

#col1{
    /*display: block;*/
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}
#col2{
    /*display: block;*/
    width:40%;
    float:right;
}
```

This is HTML:

```
<div id="table_wrap">
<table >
    <tbody>
        <tr id="table_header">
            <td id="col1">Link</td>
            <td id="col2">Department</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="table_row">
            <td id="col1"><a href="#">Dr. Clarke</a></td>
            <td id="col2">Family &amp; Consumer Sciences</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="table_row">
            <td id="col1"><a href="#">Dr. Anderson</a></td>
            <td id="col2">Sociology</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="table_row">
            <td id="col1"><a href="#">Dr. Clarke</a></td>
            <td id="col2">School of Engineering</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="table_row">
            <td id="col1">Dr. Graham Bell</td>
            <td id="col2">Biochemistry</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The hover works but text is overlaped with other text. Also even when I give the width=100% for row it doesn't seem to spread through out the screen.
I declared the header to stay solid, and all other rows to give a hover effect.

This is fiddle for my work:
http://jsfiddle.net/veniarya/6n63031t/

Comment: By changing a table element to `display:block` you've removed the table rendering mode, which is why things overlap. Remove these and you'll find things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- You should not use same id name multiple times on a page. Change them to classes
- Don't use `display:block;` on table elements, that changes the table layout
- "Link" and "Departemnt" should be in `<thead>`
- Apply the border radius to the table cell `<th>` or `<td>` rahter than `<tr>`
- It's rather safe to use unprefixed `border-radius` [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/6n63031t/10/

Updated HTML:

```
<div id="table_wrap">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table_header">
                <th class="col1">Link</th>
                <th class="col2">Department</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table_row">
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Dr. Clarke</a></td>
                <td class="col2">Family &amp; Consumer Sciences</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table_row">
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Dr. Anderson</a></td>
                <td class="col2">Sociology</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table_row">
                <td class="col1"><a href="#">Dr. Clarke</a></td>
                <td class="col2">School of Engineering</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table_row">
                <td class="col1">Dr. Graham Bell</td>
                <td class="col2">Biochemistry</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table_header th,
.table_row td {
    padding:10px;
}

.table_header {
    background: #dfdbd2;
}

.table_header .col1,
.table_row .col1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.table_header .col2,
.table_row .col2 {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.table_row:hover {
    background:#f0eade;
}

.col1 {
    width:40%;
    text-align: left;
}

.col2 {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please, try to have unique id in html, change it for class instead, and add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to every row

Comment: I tried that with what other have to say about it, update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/veniarya/6n63031t/9/
my question in this fiddle is how do I align the text in col2 to right side, because it seems all scattered

Answer (score 1):

The rows overlap because `float:left` and `float: right` is given. If any `float` property is given then the parent elements does not takes into account the `height` of the element having `float` property. So the `height` you are getting is due to `padding` given to the parent element.

Use `text-align` instead.